# Probability of a player winning before another

Tags: probability

Given a 7 sided dice, 2 players roll it independantly simultaneously and when a player rolls a '6' he gets a prize.

What is the probability of the first player getting a prize before the second?

So my solution is to sum over all the turns j in which player 1 could win, and make the second player lose all these turns:

$$P(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(6/7)^{j-1}*(1/7)*(6/7)^j = 0.461$$
My question is if my solution is correct, and if so, why is the probability so low? It seems to me that either player 1 wins before the 2nd or the other way around, and the probability of them playing forever is 0, so it should be 0.5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternate moves, first one to roll a 6 wins: what's the probability of winning?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973508/alternate-moves-first-one-to-roll-a-6-wins-whats-the-probability-of-winning)

Comment: No, i don't understand the answer, and i'd like to know why my solution isn't correct.

Comment: On the first go, they have a 1/7 chance of winning so you know the total probability of player 1 winning can't be lower than this. If they win on the second go, both players have to have failed on the first turn and player 1 succeeds on the second. If they win on the third turn, there have been a total of 4 failed attempts to win up to that point.

Comment: but i want one of them to win, so if 1 wins on the third turn there have to have been 5 failed attempts: 4 on the first two and 1 on the third. So how's my solution wrong if we sum over all possible turns to win?

Comment: If player 1 goes first, then player 2 doesn't get a roll on the third turn if player 1 has already rolled a 6. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: So if the first player wins on his first turn, this happens with probability $\frac{1}{7}$.  If the first player fails on his first turn and the second player also fails on his first turn and the first player wins on his second turn, that occurs with probability $\frac{6}{7}\times\frac{6}{7}\times\frac{1}{7}$.  Continuing in this fashion, we should get $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\dfrac{6}{7}\right)^{2k}\cdot\dfrac{1}{7}$.  You seem to have an extra factor of $\frac{6}{7}$ in there.  That, or you are allowing ties or something

Comment: It also looks like you are making some sort of arithmetic error in evaluating your sum.  The sum you've written should have evaluated to about $\approx 0.46$

Comment: The question is unclear in its current formulation. You ask about the probability of a player "winning before another", but you define the winning condition using the formulation "the winner is", which seems to imply that there is exactly one winner, which would also agree with your consideration in the last paragraph that the probability should be $\frac12$ by symmetry. But if there is exactly one winner, then there is only winning, not winning before another. Your sum, on the other hand, seems to assume that the players roll simultaneously and only win if they get a $6$ before the other.

Comment: The turns are simultaneous

Comment: @JMoravitz for the first line to happen, player 2 must not win , so that's where the extra 6/7 comes from

Comment: So then, what happens if they tie?  If they are playing simultaneously, and player 1 and player 2 both throw a six at the same time, what happens?

Comment: I guess i didn't consider that, but winning at round j counts as rolling a 6 while the other player didn't roll a six at round j or any round before. maybe i should reformulate the question to: whoever rolls a 6 gets a prize and what's the probability of player 1 getting a prize before player 2

Comment: "*Winning at round j counts as rolling a 6 while the other player didn't roll a 6 at round j or any round before*"  So... if on round three both players rolled a six, now noone wins ever?  Player 1 doesn't win on round 3 because player two rolled a 6 on round 3 or before, same for player 2... and then player 1 doesn't win on some later round where he did roll a 6 since player 2 rolled a six on round 3 which was before the later round?

Comment: You've corrected the evaluation of your summation at least.  Now... notice that the probability that they tie can also be calculated and will wind up being $\frac{1}{13}$.  Now, since there is in your formulation of the problem no benefit to being the first player or the second player (*which is a non-standard formulation to the problem*), they are equally likely to win so long as a tie doesn't occur.  The probability is then $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{12}{13} = \frac{6}{13}\approx 0.461538\dots$ same as what you'd calculate for your summation.

Comment: In the standard formulation of the problem, where they *take turns*, so player $A$ takes a turn, and only if $A$ doesn't win, then $B$ takes a turn, repeating the process, or equivalently, the game you describe but "*ties count as a win for player $A$*" that winds up being a probability of winning for player $A$ as being higher and will be $\frac{7}{13}$, which you would have gotten had you followed the earlier described arguments or the method in the linked question.

Comment: Now... for one final way you can see the probability... imagine we let them play the game and allow player 2 to take a final turn on the final round even if player 1 had rolled a 6.  Ignore *everything* except the final round.  We know that there is at least one 6 rolled, but beyond that, all possibilities with at least one six rolled *are equally likely to have occurred.*  $(1,6),(2,6),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(7,6)$ all count as wins for player 2 while $(6,1),(6,2),(6,3),(6,4),(6,5),(6,7)$ count as wins for player 1 and $(6,6)$ either counts as a tie or a win for player 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments, initially your probability was *so low* because of an arithmetic mistake.

After fixing your mistake, your answer is correct for the problem where the players play simultaneously and ties don't count as a win for either player.

As for why the probability isn't $\frac{1}{2}$, it is because ties are possible.  If we were to calculate the probability of a tie using whatever method, we'll find the probability of a tie is $\frac{1}{13}$ in which case the probability of winning for a particular player is half of the probability of no tie occurring and is as such $\frac{6}{13}$ and this is the same for both players.

The infinite summation approach is perfectly correct and is often one of the first approaches new students will attempt to use for this, though it can often lead to headaches because of the algebra and arithmetic required to complete the problem and so is not preferred once you have developed more skills.

---

My preferred explanation for this... Look at the outcome of the final round, whichever round that happened to be, ignoring all other rounds.  Allow player 2 to take his/her final turn even if player 1 were poised to win in the event that you are playing with the rules that the turns within each round don't occur simultaneously.

Since it is the final round, we know that the outcomes of the dice had to be one of the $7+7-1=13$ possibilities: $(6,1),(6,2),(6,3),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6),(6,7),(1,6),(2,6),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(7,6)$.  (*Be careful not to count $(6,6)$ twice*).

We recognize that these outcomes were equally likely to have occurred.

Six of them correspond to player 1 winning (*in the event that $(6,6)$ doesn't count as a win for $A$ but instead as a tie, otherwise there are seven outcomes corresponding to a win for player 1*) out of the thirteen equally likely outcomes.  Thus, the probability of player one winning is $\dfrac{6}{13}$.